# How to Save Gif file From ImageView Android Share using Intent

Tags: android

I am displaying gif image from url in imageview and its working perfect.Now i want to share this gif file using share intent but not working its share simple image instead of gif.

```
  protected void shareIntent() {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    OutputStream output;
    img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    // Retrieve the image from the res folder
    bitmap = img.getDrawingCache();

    // Find the SD Card path
    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Create a new folder AndroidBegin in SD Card
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Share Image/");
    dir.mkdirs();

    // Create a name for the saved image
    File file = new File(dir, "sample_wallpaper.gif");

    try {

        // Share Intent
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        // Type of file to share
        share.setType("image/gif");

        output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();

        // Locate the image to Share
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        // Pass the image into an Intnet
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        // Show the social share chooser list
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image "));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please help ................

Comment: Don't share from the `ImageView`. Share the GIF that you used to put in the `ImageView`. Also, `file` schemes, like you get from `Uri.fromFile()`, [are banned on Android 7.0+](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare Didn't get please explain.

Comment: Your `ImageView` did not magically get a GIF. You put it there. Instead of sharing the contents of the `ImageView`, share the GIF from wherever you got it.

Comment: Now i am getting the error "The file format is not supported"

Comment: Not every app is required to support GIF. Beyond that, you might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide your modified [mcve].